# Initializing an ordered map?

Tags: java, hashmap, ordered-map

I'm having trouble on how to create a new ordered map that reads a file char by char. Here is the beginning of my program

```
public class Practice {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the file name to random write: ");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out
        .print("Enter nGram length, 1 is like random, 12 is like the book: ");
    int nGramLength = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.close();

    Practice rw = new Practice(fileName, nGramLength);
    rw.printRandom(500);
  }

  private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Character>> all;
  private int nGramLength;
  private String fileName;
  private StringBuilder theText;
  private static Random generator;
  private String nGram;

  public Practice(String fileName, int nGramLength) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.nGramLength = nGramLength;
    generator = new Random();
    makeTheText();
    setRandomNGram();
    setUpMap(); // Algorithm considered during section.  
  }

  private void makeTheText() {
    Scanner inFile = null;
    try {
      inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    theText = new StringBuilder();
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
      theText = theText.append(inFile.nextLine().trim());
      theText = theText.append(' ');
    }
  }

  public void setRandomNGram() {
    generator = new Random();
    int temp = theText.length() - nGramLength - 1;
    int start = generator.nextInt(temp);
    nGram = theText.substring(start, start + nGramLength);
  }

  // Read theText char by char to build a OrderedMaps where
  // every possible nGram exists with the list of followers. 
  // This method need these three instance variables:    
  //    nGramLength   theText  all
  private void setUpMap() {
    // TODO: Implement this method
      for(int i = 0; i < nGramLength; i++)
      {
          ArrayList<Character> key = all.get(i);
      }
      }

  // Print chars random characters.  Please insert line breaks to make your
  // output readable to the poor grader :-)
  void printRandom(int howMany) {
    // TODO: Implement this method
  }
}
```

I need to work on the last two methods, but I am confused as to how to iterate through a hashmap

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a `HashMap` by iterating over its `entrySet()`.  That will give you both the key and value:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Character>> entry : all) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Alternatively you can iterate only over its `keySet()` or `valueSet()`, but it sounds as if you want both key and value here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you do not iterator over a map. Maps do not have an iterator because that would make no sense. What would it iterator over the keys the values or both. The solution is turn your keys or values into a collection. You do this with the values method (returns a collection of the values) and keySet method (returns a set of the keys in the map) You can then call those collection's iterator methods.